# largest bitwise-or subset with a maximum number of on bits?

Tags: algorithms, sets, weighted-graphs

Suppose I have the following set of bit sets:

```
 [1,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
 [2,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0     1
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
 [4,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1     0
 [6,]    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0     0
 [7,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     1
 [8,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0     1
[10,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0     0
```

How would I go about finding the largest set such that the bitwise-or of that set does not exceed n bits in the "on" position.

For example, if I *or* rows 1 & 10...

```
 [1,]         0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
[10,]         0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0     0
[1 or 10,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    0     0
```

This gives me 7 bits in the "on" position.

Now suppose my limit was 8 bits... how would I go about finding the largest set?

Edit:  I know how to do this as a mixed-integer-linear program, but I'm assuming there's a nifty graph approach.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-hard. It is called "the minimum-k-union problem". Given a universe $U$ and a family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ over this universe. Are there $k$ distinct sets in $F$ such that the union of all these sets has size at most $d$.

Your presentation is the matrix formulation of this problem where each column corresponds to an element in the universe and each row corresponds to a set in the family. We are looking for $k$ rows such that the number of columns having at least one "1" is at most $d$.

The Problem is NP-hard and has approximation algorithms. Here is a [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07866) for one of them.